# Use web service in java script with scriptmanagerporxy in ascx

Tags: javascript, ajax, telerik, ascx

I have a web site. In site master page I use Telerik RadScriptManager.When I add a web service to it works well.But I want to add the web service in each page. Each page is ascx. I found ScriptManagerProxy but when I put it in ascx I can't call from Java script and if I put ScriptManagerProxy in site master it works. I want to add the web service in each page 
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ali, I think you don't need a ScriptManagerProxy. Can't you call this web service from the code-behind of the MasterPage or the code behind of the User Control?

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to create for each page and I want add web service only on that in java script can you more explain your answer